# R: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r, function, na

When i use a package named HydroMe to fit a model, some data groups will return the following errors:

```
Error in qr.default(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) : 
 NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Actually,there is no missing value in the data  groups.
the codes are as followed:

```
library(HydroMe)
fortst<-read.csv(file="F:/fortst.csv")
van.lis <-nlsList(y~SSvan(x,Thr, Ths, alp, scal)|Sample,data=fortst)
```

the example data canbe download from here:

```
http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/9/13/3346981/fortst.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

The variables `Thr`, `Ths`, `alp`, and `scal` are not in your data frame or in `fortst.csv`. Thus, when they're referred to in the `y~SSvan(x,Thr, Ths, alp, scal)|Sample` formula, they're NA.

Comment: while,in fact,Thr，Ths,alp and scal are just what i want to get through this process.x and y are in my data frame and were referred in this formula. Another data with the similar structure perform well.Such as the following data.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for this error could be that the variable defined in your data frame is different from their actual data type.  for eg  you define 'Char' for 'Date' vaiable .