# NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function error with mantelhaen.test()

Tags: r

I have a 100k row dataframe on which I want to compute a Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test.

My variables are the educational level and a computed score factored in quantiles, and my grouping variable is the sex, and the code line looks like this :

```
mantelhaen.test(db$education, db$score.grouped, db$sex)
```

This code throws this error and warning :

> Error in qr.default(a, tol = tol) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
>   In addition: Warning message: In ntot * rowsums : NAs produced by integer overflow

The error seems to be caused by my first variable, as on 7 variables tested I got the problem with only 2 of them, which seems to share no obvious common thing.

Missing values and factor levels don't seem to differ between variables which throws error and variable which doesn't. I tried with complete cases (with `na.omit`) and the problem persists.

What does trigger this error ? does it mean ?
How can I get rid of it ?

Interesting posts : [R: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390978/r-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-1), [What is integer overflow in R and how can it happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)

**ADDENDUM** : Here is the result of `str` (failures are `education` and `imc.cl`):

```
str(db[c("education","score.grouped","sex", ...)])
'data.frame':   104382 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ age.cl: Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "<30 ans"<"30-40 ans"<..: 5 2 1 1 3 4 2 3 4 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "age"
 $ emploi2          : Factor w/ 8 levels "Agriculteurs exploitants",..: 3 5 6 8 8 8 8 3 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "CSP"
 $ tabac            : Factor w/ 4 levels "ancien fumeur",..: 4 1 4 4 3 4 4 1 4 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "tabac"
 $ situ_mari2       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Vit seul","Divorsé, séparé ou veuf",..: 3 2 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "marriage"
 $ education        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Universitaire",..: 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ revenu.cl        : Factor w/ 4 levels "<1800 euros/uc",..: 3 4 2 NA 4 1 1 4 4 1 ...
 $ imc.cl           : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "Maigre"<"Normal"<..: 2 2 1 2 3 1 3 2 2 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "IMC"
```

**EDIT** : by diving inside the function, the error and warning are caused by a call to `qr.solve`. I don't understand anything about this but I'll try to dive deeper
**EDIT2** : inside `qr.solve`, the error is thrown by a `Fortran` call to `.F_dqrdc2`. This is so much beyond my level my nose is starting to bleed.
**EDIT3** : I tried to `head` my data to find out which line is in cause :

```
db2 = db %>% head(99787)   #fails at 99788
db2 = db %>% tail(99698)   #fails at 99699
mantelhaen.test(db2$education, db2$score.grouped, db2$sex)
```

This gives me not much information but maybe it could give you.

Comment: The product of two integer numbers gets too large to be an integer, e.g., `10L * 2147483646L` reproduces the warning. That happens as a result of properties of your data. Without a reproducible example we can't really help more.

Comment: Yes, I saw some posts about this warning, this is what I understood. But how can I give a 100k rows reproducible example ?

Comment: @Roland could you please take a look at my edits ? Have you got an idea of how can I give you a reproducible example ?

Comment: can you show us `str(db[c("education","score.grouped","sex")])` ? Can you write code to randomly generate a data set with 100K rows with similar characteristics that causes the same error?

Comment: @BenBolker I added the `str` output. Sorry but I'm affraid I cannot generate them, I don't even know where to start for this. Please note that I tried 7 variables and only education and another throwed this error.

Comment: OK, can you edit to post `str(db)`  (i.e. all of the variables) and tell us which other one failed?

Comment: This is what I tried to reproduce (it worked though): `set.seed(101); n <- 78000;
db <- data.frame(education=
                   factor(sample(1:3,replace=TRUE,size=n)),
                 score=
                   factor(sample(1:5,replace=TRUE,size=n)),
                 sex=
                   sample(c("M","F"),replace=TRUE,size=n)); mantelhaen.test(db$education, db$score, db$sex)`

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, no problem to make an example of a working test, but I have no clue about how to reproduce the error (since I don't know what cause it). I made the edits in `str` output. Thanks for your help !

Comment: one more hint: I think the problem probably starts at your warning (the overflow warning) - the stuff inside `qr.solve()` is downstream of that. With this big a data set you could probably try `exact=FALSE` ...

Comment: @BenBolker `exact=FALSE` is the default value. I tried with `correct=FALSE` but the error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem by making the data set bigger.

```
set.seed(101); n <- 500000
db <- data.frame(education=
                   factor(sample(1:3,replace=TRUE,size=n)),
                 score=
                   factor(sample(1:5,replace=TRUE,size=n)),
                 sex=
                   sample(c("M","F"),replace=TRUE,size=n))
```

After this, `mantelhaen.test(db$education, db$score, db$sex)` gives the reported error.

Thankfully, the real problem is not within the guts of the QR decomposition code: rather, it occurs when setting up a matrix prior to QR decomposition. There are two computations, `ntot*colsums` and `ntot*rowsums`, that overflow R's capacity for integer computation. There's a relatively easy way to work around this by creating a modified version of the function:

- copy the source code: `dump("mantelhaen.test",file="my_mh.R")`
- edit the source code

  - l. 1: modify name of function to my_mantelhaen.test (to avoid confusion)
  - lines 199 and 200: change `ntot` to `as.numeric(ntot)`, converting the integer to double precision before the overflow happens
- `source("my_mh.R")` to read in the new function

Now

```
my_mantelhaen.test(db$education, db$score, db$sex)
```

should work.
You should *definitely* test the new function against the old function for cases where it works to make sure you get the same answer.

Now posted to the [R bug list](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17383), we'll see what happens ...

**update** 11 May 2018: this is [fixed in the development version of R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L59) (3.6 to be).

Comment: I tested it, this gives exact same results on all 5 variables. But maybe I should use `my_mantelhaen.test()` as the error function of a `tryCatch()`.

Comment: Thank you. This was a great help!